# Transfer tokens among multiple accounts in single function

Tags: solidity, tokens, ethereumj

I want the user to transfer tokens to an wallet instead of smart contract.

```
function getTokens () public {

    require (token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount));
    require (token.transfer(NewWalletAddress, amount));
}
```

Initial tokes in contract address and NewWalletAddress is 0.

Will the above code work correctly in Eth mainnet? Will the 2 transfers take place or will there be any issues. or do we have another approach? Please suggest ideas

Comment: What's the purpose? Why wouldn't you just write `require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, NewWalletAddress, amount);` in one step?

Comment: why dont you just try it

Comment: @smarx I thought about that too. When directly transferred to walletaddress, the user has to approve both the contract and NewWalletaddress.  What will be the values of  approve datastructure after the function call.

Comment: That's not true. The original holder of the tokens just has to `approve` whatever address is going to call `transferFrom`.

Comment: That said, your existing code is fine; it's just going to be less efficient (and thus more expensive due to gas costs).